# how to open a div link into the same div

Tags: html, hyperlink

I want the links on my `<div id="content">` to open on the same `<div id="content">`. I don't want the links to open as new pages and I don't want to go out of my index file. 
In other words, I want to use my homepage as a browser.
Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: Easy? that depends on the coder.  It can be done quite simply using javascript and jquery.

Comment: Sounds like you want an iframe

Comment: Yes. I want an iframe but without scrollbars. :)

Comment: @Temhem don't think thats possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use templates and routing with angularJs https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating that i think it's the best solution